# Azure DevOps build YML not conditionals not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I'm attempting to set the build config based on the source branch in the build yml as well as set release version variables.

`isRelease` is getting set to true or false appropriately as I test on different branches, however, the conditionals are not working. No matter what `isRelease` is (true/false), build config is always '`Debug`'. I've tried multiple syntaxes. Any help?

I have this:

```
 trigger:
      branches:
       include:
         - develop,
         - release/*,
         - Release/*
    
    pool:
      name: 'MyPool'
    
    variables: 
      isRelease: $[contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release')]
    
      ${{ if eq(variables['isRelease'], 'true') }}:
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
        version.Major: '1',
        version.Minor: $[counter(variables['version.Major'], 1)]
        versionNumber: $(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    
      ${{ if eq(variables['isRelease'], 'false') }}:
        buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
    
    steps...
      echo: $(buildConfiguration) // is echoing literally $(buildConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the additional variable and comparing the source branch directly, as in:

```yaml
    variables: 
   
      ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release') }}:
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
        version.Major: '1',
        version.Minor: $[counter(variables['version.Major'], 1)]
        versionNumber: $(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    
      ${{ if not(contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release')) }}:
        buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
```

From the Microsoft doc on template expressions:

> In a compile-time expression (${{  }}), you have access to parameters and statically defined variables

To me that suggests that a variable with a runtime setting won't be able to "feed" that template expression.

Comment: if I do your first option, it doesn't build, if I do your second, it doesn't set the build config at all when I echo it to the log.

Comment: Check, so the `['varname`]` syntax is what you need. This is a little hard to debug without more complete YAML, but can you try putting in a step before this that does: `- pwsh: Write-Host "${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}"`? and also `- pwsh: Write-Host "${{ variables['isRelease'] }}"`? I want to get down to what's getting assigned and what's not.

Comment: I updated the original post with your syntax.

Comment: source branch gives me /refs/heads/branch-name and isRelease gives me False (since I built on a branch which doesn't contain release.

Comment: OK, I'd like to try not using the intermediary variable and just go after the source branch directly (see above).

Comment: There are some truly wonky variable behaviors that come into play with template expressions. Variables that are declared in the file, as well as system variables, are available to them, but I'm wondering if using a runtime variable expression in declaring the variable sets the value too late for the template expression?

Comment: yeah, could be.